# How to make the images in magento visible in local server which are broken state?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am doing a project in magento.I downloaded all its files and databse onto local server.The images in the website and also in the admin panel is in broken state in local server are in broken state.Can anyone tell a way to fix it ?

Comment: have you downloaded media folder as well ?

Comment: if no download it and clear all cache from admin

Comment: I have downloaded the media folder...the images are there in the media/catalog/products.. folder..

Comment: have you checked image by opening in image viewer ? they all are good or corrupted ?

Comment: check the permission of media folder.

Comment: i opened the image by inspecting in a new tab..its also showing error

Comment: how to check the permission of the media folder..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having permission issue of the folder. The media folder should be writable, If you are using linux then try

`sudo chmod 777 -R media/`
and clear the cache